# Exchange 2010: Giving a user calendar-viewing access without e-mail access

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, calendar

We want to give a `User A`  access to view `User B`'s shared calendar without giving `user A` a mailbox on the Exchange instance. `User A` will have a mailbox in another non-Exchange server in our network.

How could we accomplish this? If there are multiple options, what are the caveats?

Comment: I am virtually certain you cannot do what you want to do. There may be a 3rd party tool here: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/share.asp

Comment: As far as I could tell, the article is about the sharing part. The sharing of calendars is not that difficult. What we are trying to do now is having a Calendar-only user (i.e., with no Exchange e-mail).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Exchange 2010 SP1, you could enable Internet Calendar Sharing and publish `User B`'s calendar in iCalendar format for `User A` to pick up.

This [Microsoft Exchange Team Blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/02/16/exchange-2010-sp1-and-exchange-online-office-365-calendaring-faq.aspx) goes into detail on the subject, though it's a bit wordy and mixed in with some other cloud-peddling bumph. Probably the most relevant bullet point to you is this one:

> - **Internet Calendar Sharing** allows users to share (and subscribe to) calendar data in iCalendar format with any anybody, inside or outside the organization, whether those recipients are using Exchange, another platform, or simply a web browser. Internet Calendar Sharing does not require authenticated access or Federated Trust, and the only setup required is for the Exchange administrator to turn the feature on.

The [Enable Internet Calendar Publishing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607475.aspx) notes on TechNet go through the process which is basically enabling the feature with a couple of cmdlets, creating a sharing policy and assigning it to mailboxes.

To actually share the calendar, `User B` can use either Outlook 2010 or OWA ([instructions](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/beta/ff658276.aspx?sl=1)), or you as the administrator can use PowerShell to publish a calendar for the user.